# Python tkinter:Update label tag , Event and label in different classes

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have the problem that i want to update a label when i push on a button.But the event and the label are in different classes that make it hard to assign it.Here is how i try it.First the Event class:

```
class EventsBinding(WindowInhalt):
    def Test(self, event):
        print("gedrückt")

    def root_destroy(self, event):
        self.root.destroy()

    def Credits(self, event):
        window = WindowInhalt()
        window.label1.config(text="update") #here i try it to update the label
```

And Second here is the class with the label:

```
class WindowInhalt():
    def label4(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        label = Label(self.root, text="Credits", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Credits) #here i assign the event
        label.place(x=200, y=280, width="400", height="20")
```

And here is the full code if you need them:

```
#Mein Erstes Gui Python Programm mit Tkinter
#Created: July,2017
#Creator: Yuto
from tkinter import *

#class für den Inhalt des Windows z.b. label
class WindowInhalt():
    def label1(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        label = Label(self.root, text="Willkommen zu meinem Text Adventure", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Test)
        label.place(x=200, y=50, width="400", height="20")

    def label2(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        label = Label(self.root, text="spielen", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Test)
        label.place(x=200, y=120, width="400", height="20")

    def label3(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        label = Label(self.root, text="Settings", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Test)
        label.place(x=200, y=200, width="400", height="20")

    def label4(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        label = Label(self.root, text="Credits", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Credits)
        label.place(x=200, y=280, width="400", height="20")

    def Button(self):
        events_binding = EventsBinding()
        button = Button(self.root, text="Spiel verlassen", command=self.root.destroy)
        button.place(x=680, y=340, width="110", height="40")



class EventsBinding(WindowInhalt):
    def Test(self, event):
        print("gedrückt")

    def root_destroy(self, event):
        self.root.destroy()

    def Credits(self, event):
        window = WindowInhalt()
        window.label1.config(text="update")



#class für das Window an sich hier wird dann auch z.b. Inhalt eingebunden
class Window(WindowInhalt):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label1()
        self.label2()
        self.label3()
        self.label4()
        self.Button()
        self.windowSettings()

    #settings für das window z.b. größe
    def windowSettings(self):
        self.root.configure(background="lightyellow")
        self.root.title("GUI LALALLALALA")
        self.root.wm_geometry("800x400+600+300")
        self.root.mainloop()



#Only ausführen wenn es nicht eingebunden ist
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starten")
    w = Window()
else:
    print("Dise Datei bitte nicht einbinden!")
```

And here if you need him too the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme\python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Programme/PyCharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.4/Projekt/gui game.py", line 48, in Credits
    window.label1.config(text="update")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I am greatfull for help thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:** Now i have it.I have to change the variable also so

```
label4 = Label(text="update", fg="black", bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label4.place(x=200, y=280, width="400", height="20")
```

Thank you very much for your help respectively for your hint  Bryan Oakley and i wish you have a nice day :)

Comment: what do you think `window.label1` is, and have you verified that it is actually what you think it is?

Comment: i cant asign normal label1 also i have to asign the class from label1 first and then from the class call the variable

Comment: I don't think any of that answered my question. The point is, `window.label1` is not what you think it is. It's a function, and you seem to think it's a widget.

Comment: i thought label1 is in this case a variable :/

Comment: okay i try to check a way to change a variable(from a function)from outsite a function